# What are the fasting rules for 'triratri vrata' followed by Lila?

Tags: smriti, fasting, vrata, yoga-vashishtha

Lila did a vrata for pleasing Saraswathi. Fewer details have been given in Yoga Vasista regarding the fasting rules of the vrata. The relevant excerpts regarding fasting rules are given below

> Having determined so, she betook herself to observe the strict
> ceremonials of the Sastra, and without the knowledge of her lord.
> **She kept her fasts, and broke them at the end of every third night**;and then entertained the gods, Brahmans, the priests and holy
> people, with feasts and due honours. She was then employed in the
> performance of her daily ablutions, in her act of alms-giving, in the
> observance of her austerities and in meditation; in all of which she
> was painstaking, an observant of the rules of pious theism. She
> attended also to her incognizant husband at stated times, and
> ministered unto him to the utmost, her duties as required by law and
> usage. Thus observant of her vows, the young princess passed a hundred
> of her **trinoctial ceremony**, with resolute and persevering
> pains-taking and unfailing austerities.
>
> [[30-43, Chapter 16, Utpatti Khanda,
> Yoga Vasistha]](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/yoga-vasistha-english/d/doc118070.html)

I want to know more details regarding fasting rules of the vrata followed by Lila from any other scriptures especially smritis if possible.